# Todoist item actions contextmenu plugin for jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, contextmenu

I wan to know if a jQuery plugin exists to do a menu action like Todoist? When you want to do an action, like edit item, a arrow appear on the row item and when you click it, a context menu(with the left click) appears and some actions are possbile to do for this Item. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are ones out there.  Have you tried to Googling?

http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2010/03/ajax-todo-list-jquery-php-mysql-css/demo.php